# Windows 7 - Find all files and folders larger than a given size

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I want to find all files and folders on my C: drive that are larger than a given size, since I've forgotten half of what I have on there.

Typing "size:>100MB" into the search box in Windows Explorer just returns "No items match your search" for some reason.

I found a program called Agent Ransack (https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) that does mostly what I want, but it doesn't search folders themselves.

Is there another program that I can use which will show me files AND folders larger than a given size, or get windows search to do what it's supposed to?

Comment: Folders don’t take any space. Files do. So it doesn’t make any sense to “search files and folders larger than a given size.” What you mean to say is to find folders that contain a large amount of file data, which is still just searching for files.

Comment: Well, of course directories (folders) take space, although Windows conceals that from users.  But if you run `dir/b` with output to a file, the size of that file gives you a rough approximation of the size of the directory — they typically range from a few KB to a few hundred KB.  To have a folder larger than 1 MB would be rare.

Comment: You might try third-party tools intended specifically to show disk usage, as as TreeSize Free. To get a more complete listing of files, run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the drive that you want to search and type: `size:gigantic` in the search box.

Comment: I did that and I still get "no items match your search."

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by size, so that the largest files appear at the top of the list. If you want to do that across an entire drive, you can type *.* in the search box, and when the results start to appear, click the "Size" column heading. It will take some time for all the files to be listed, and it won't be sorted by size until everything is displayed.